# Cropping Image - crop invalid argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to implement a Cropping feature in a Rails app. Basically I am following the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?view=asciicast).
But when it try cropping the image a see this in console.

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/rc/y5p0pv054xb20rtgwhzx5pzc0000gn/T/98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-dffwla.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/rc/y5p0pv054xb20rtgwhzx5pzc0000gn/T/98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/rc/y5p0pv054xb20rtgwhzx5pzc0000gn/T/98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/rc/y5p0pv054xb20rtgwhzx5pzc0000gn/T/98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp.jpg[0]' -crop '300 x 300 + 200 + 31 '-auto-orient -resize "500x500>" '/var/folders/rc/y5p0pv054xb20rtgwhzx5pzc0000gn/T/98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp20150505-19502-bwuuga'
convert: InvalidArgument `-crop': 300 x 300 + 200 + 31 -auto-orient @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1083.
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the thumbnail for 98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/rc/y5p0pv054xb20rtgwhzx5pzc0000gn/T/98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/rc/y5p0pv054xb20rtgwhzx5pzc0000gn/T/98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/rc/y5p0pv054xb20rtgwhzx5pzc0000gn/T/98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp.jpg[0]' -crop '300 x 300 + 200 + 31 '-auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/var/folders/rc/y5p0pv054xb20rtgwhzx5pzc0000gn/T/98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp20150505-19502-8qahjf'
convert: InvalidArgument `-crop': 300 x 300 + 200 + 31 -auto-orient @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1083.
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the thumbnail for 98fc51f68e50c6db6eb4594f625b4b7a20150505-19502-qz95yp>
```

The relevant code here is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
module Paperclip
  class Cropper < Thumbnail

    def transformation_command 
      if crop_command 
        r = super 
        if r.class == Array 
          r = r.join(' ') 
        end 
        crop_command + r.sub(/ -crop \S+/, '') 
      else 
        super 
      end
    end

    def crop_command
      target = @attachment.instance
      if target.cropping?
        y = target.crop_y.to_i
        x = target.crop_x.to_i
        w = target.crop_w.to_i
        h = target.crop_h.to_i

        " -crop \"#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}\""

      end 
    end
  end
end
```

I just note that if I insert a space at end of this line:

" -crop \"#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}\""

The code entered in a infinite looping. Then if I stop the server, and access the page, I see the image cropped.

I searched for this and found some people with similar issue. So I take a look at my `crop command` method. I tried many form of 'format' the `crop` command, but without success.

Any help here will be great.

Thanks

Comment: You should assume that nobody else has seen the railscast, and just describe what you are trying to do, eg "i'm using such and such a gem, and my code is thus, and this is the error i get"

Comment: @MaxWilliams I just quoted the railscast references to issues reference. I will update the question with relevant code. Thanks

Comment: Have you somehow got spaces between the parts of the crop geometry? Normally, it is like this `-crop 300x300+200+31` i.e. all bunched up together.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes. I try with spaces and without spaces. I just add some information about this at the question. Thanks

Comment: You also have a `greater than` sign `>` in the `-resize` that may need escaping. Maybe try removing the `-resize` altogether initially.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I dont know if you see the code I posted. But I don't know how to remove the ```>```...

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak Ruby or Paperclip. Can you output the full ImageMagick command somehow just before you execute it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77017/discussion-between-elf-and-mark-setchell).